# Sustainsys Saml2 return 404 when call back from iDP on route Saml2/Acs

Tags: c#, identityserver4, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have the following property:

IDP: Azure AD

Service Provider: .Net 6 ( with IdentityServer4)

I was able to read Identity providers from the database instead of adding in the startup.cs like .AddSaml2("Saml2").

When **I add .AddSaml2()** then proper redirect is happening to our external callback endpoint after user authentication.

When **I don't add .AddSaml2()** in startup.cs then I see 'https://localhost:74329/Saml2/Acs' is not found (404).

Am I missing anything?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the identity providers is just one of the things that `.AddSaml2()` does. Another is to register the handler that responds to `/Saml2/Acs`. Even if you load your identity providers from the DB, you need the call to `AddSaml2()`.